# Can I get the type of a Lazy value before creating the value?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class "MyClass" with a private list property set in the following way:

```
List = new List<Lazy<BaseClass>> {
    new Lazy<BaseClass>(() => new DerivedClassA(x)),
    new Lazy<BaseClass>(() => new DerivedClassB(x, y)),
    new Lazy<BaseClass>(() => new DerivedClassC())
};
```

And a method on the same class:

```
public void OpenTab<T>();
```

Which I would like to call as such:

```
myClassObject.OpenTab<DerivedClassA>();
```

Which will then set a property in `MyClass` with the value from the lazy instance in `List` which creates that type.

Is there a way that I can use the type parameter in `OpenTab` to ensure that I *only* create the value from the list of lazy instances which creates a value of the specified type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you could store them in a `Dictionary<Type, Lazy<Type>>`

```
List = new Dictionary<Type, Lazy<BaseClass>> {
    [typeof(DerivedClassA)] = new Lazy<BaseClass>(() => new DerivedClassA(x)),
    [typeof(DerivedClassB)] = new Lazy<BaseClass>(() => new DerivedClassB(x, y)),
    [typeof(DerivedClassC)] = new Lazy<BaseClass>(() => new DerivedClassC())
};

public void OpenTab<T>()
{
   var instance = List[typeof(T)].Value;
   // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: To add to this: if you wanted to avoid the repitition of the type, you could define a method e.g. `void Register<T>(Func<T> factory) where T : BaseClass { dict.Add(typeof(T), new Lazy<BaseClass>(() => factory())); }` then `Register(() => new DerivedClassA(x))`, etc